# How do I set the archive Bit of a file shared with samba?

Tags: samba

A file is hosted by a samba server (18.04). The file contains a backup of this *18.04-server*. Some MS-Based backup tool (on a windows-server) needs a so called Archive-Bit set, to backup this specific file. If not set, this file is ignored during the backup from *18.04-server* to *windows-server*.

I feed my shared folder via the local file system on the samba host `/var/mySharedFolder/`. Which ever file I put it the local folder it's shown in the samba share entered by an other *windows-server* via `//18.04-server/mySharedFolder`.

How can I set the archive bit from *18.04-server* side to the uploaded file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default **Samba preserves archive file attribute (from DOS/Windows file system) on Linux file system.**

Here's a detailed explanation about [preserving archive attribute](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_03.html).

It's done by setting the executable bit for for the owner when a file has archive attribute on; for example:

```
-rw-rw----  1 nobody nogroup    0 Nov 26 11:21 file_no_arch.txt
-rwxrw----  1 nobody nogroup    0 Nov 26 11:55 smb_crt.txt
```

As you can see the file "file_no_arch.txt" has executable bit off and when you view it in windows it will say it's non archive.
File "smb_crt.txt" has this bit on so it will have archive attribute on too.

[image]

**If the files uploaded from windows box do not have archive attribute set** - check your Samba configuration (/etc/samba/smb.conf) - specifically two things:

1. make sure there's no "map archive = no" line in the file. If it's there just delete or comment it.
2. check [mySharedFolder] section - if there's "create mask = 0600" change it to "create mask = 0700" or 0755 to give other linux users' ability to view files.

For testing I've set up a Debian 9 box and installed Samba as explained [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-debian-9-stretch-linux).
The other system used for testing was Windows server 2012.

**If you just want to make windows box think, the file has archive attribute on then you can just type:**

```
chmod +x my_backup_file.zip
```

**And if you use some script to create this backup file then just put this command in it and every file will have this bit on.**

My example smb.conf file:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[public]
  comment = public anonymous access
  path = /var/samba/
  browsable =yes
  create mask = 0760
  directory mask = 0771
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
```

Comment: the users x-bit does the trick indeed! thank you, for this great answer and the time you put in it! Where did you get this info from? Did oversee some obvious aspects? Is there some logic behind it?

Comment: Nice to hear that you appreciate my input - I've has some free time and since I'm using similar setup at my home I wanted to figure this out. You can also map other windows attributes like "hidden" or "system" by putting "set system = yes" or "set hidden". From what I know only archive is preserved by default.